# No Sound on TV when Laptop connected through HDMI, but is listed as Default Device

Tags: windows, audio, hdmi, tv, system-sounds

Yesterday, I was watching some movies on my TV through my laptop, using the HDMI cable, it was working just fine. But this morning when I plugged it in, there is absolutely no sound. Both the TV and the laptop have sound individually when they are not connected, but when I connect the two, through the HDMI cable, the sound is muted on the laptop.

Even when I manually change the sound, immediately when I click off of the slider, the laptop mutes itself again. The TV is listed as the default device, and as I said, it was working just fine earlier, so I have no idea why it won't work today! Please can someone help?